# Creation of roles in fosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I currently have `ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]` and I wanted to add a new role with permissions between normal user and admin.
I'm completely new to symfony in general and I read some documentation about it, but I just can't understand the process of creating a new role.
First things first: should I do

```
ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_NEW_ROLE]
```

or

```
ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
ROLE_NEW_ROLE: ROLE_USER
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

And second: Besides this change in `security.yml`, in what files do I need to change something in order to just complete the creation of a role (not talking about give specific permissions to this new role yet).

I don't know if this is a stupid question, but I'm fairly lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Symfony community!

To put it simply, the **definition of roles** and the **hierarchy** are totally different.

You can define different roles for your users without specifying them in your project. With the promote / demote command, for example:

```
php app/console fos:user:promote
php app/console fos:user:demote
```

On the other hand, if you want to **create a hierarchy between User and Admin**, you can assign the user member privileges:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_NEW_ROLE: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_NEW_ROLE
```

That's all !